# What are adjectives to describe the change of a number by: adding / subtracting, multiplying?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm struggling to find the exact words to describe 2 ways a number change.

I have an initial number A which change periodically where

> 1/ A[new-value] = A[current-value] + C
>
> 2/ A[new-value] = A[current-value] * M

C can be a negative or positive number, and M is a real number greater than 0 (A's value decrease if M less than 1)

The two words i first thought of to describe the two changes were:

> 1/ The value of A changes **additively**
>
> 2/ The value of A changes **multiplicatively**

Both didn't sound right because A's value reduces depending on the values of C and M. I'm looking for two similar adjectives that are applicable both ways.

Comment: Does it have to be a single word?  What about 1. ... changes by addition / subtraction.  2. ... changes by multiplication / division.?

Comment: Your Q. asks for **adjectives**, but your examples use **adverbs**.  Which do you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know of a universally unambiguous solution, but if you define your terms for the purposes of the paper, I think the following two statements are natural.

> 1. *A* increases by factor *C*.
> 2. *A* scales by factor *M*.

You can leave out the term *factor* in either.

I would introduce those terms in italics and then given the definition, such as:

> *A* increases by *C* according to
>
> ```
> A_i = A_(i-1) + C.
> ```

Comment: Aren't the meaning of "increase" and "scale" leaning on "to go up"?. It's a bit awkward since A decreases too.

Comment: @SanhNguyen True, but it's not uncommon. In engineering, removing voltage from a system is called "adding loss". "Increase by -3", for example, is used. Scaling doesn't imply growth; "scaled by half" is common.